# Scala Do While Loop Not Ending

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and i'm trying to implement a do while loop but I cannot seem to get it to stop. Im not sure what i'm doing wrong. If someone could help me out that would be great. Its not the best loop I know that but I am new to the language.
Here is my code below:

```
def mnuQuestionLast(f: (String) => (String, Int)) ={
  var dataInput = true

  do {
    print("Enter 1 to Add Another 0 to Exit > ")
    var dataInput1 = f(readLine)

    if (dataInput1 == 0){
      dataInput == false
    } else {
      println{"Do the work"}
    }
  } while(dataInput == true)
}
```

Comment: Also, if your intention is to mutate `dataInput`, then `dataInput == false` will need to drop one of the `=`

Comment: For cases like this it might also be useful to learn how to use the debugging feature of your IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing a tuple type (`Tuple2[String, Int]` in this case) to `0`, which works because `==` is defined on `AnyRef`, but doesn't make much sense when you think about it. You should be looking at the second element of the tuple:

```
if (dataInput1._2 == 0)
```

Or if you want to enhance readability a bit, you can deconstruct the tuple:

```
val (line, num) = f(readLine)
if (num == 0)
```

Also, you're comparing `dataInput` with `false` (`dataInput == false`) instead of assigning false:

```
dataInput = false
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, it still will not break the loop when 0 is entered?

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer! This ends the loop even if 1 is entered?

Comment: @bigjoed It shouldn't. Is your `f` function correctly returning the right integer value?

Comment: I think that may be the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your code did not pass the functional conventions.
The value that the `f` returns is a tuple and you should check it's second value of your tuple by `dataInput1._2==0`

so you should change your if to `if(dataInput1._2==0)`

You can reconstruct your code in a better way:

```
import util.control.Breaks._


def mnuQuestionLast(f: (String) => (String, Int)) = {
  breakable {
    while (true) {
      print("Enter 1 to Add Another 0 to Exit > ")
      f(readLine) match {
        case (_, 0) => break()
        case (_,1) => println( the work"
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, if 1 is entered it also stops the loop?

Comment: @bigjoed Yes, Your if works on whatever that is not 0, and I wrote it as yours.